# How to link to a page view from a template file?

Tags: views

If I were linking to a node via a template file I would write something like this...

```
<a href="<?php echo url('node/22'); ?>">Back to blog</a>
```

I get that node ID by hovering over the node under 'Admin > Content' and looking at the node number that pops up when I hover over the 'edit' link in the bottom left (in Chrome). In the screenshot attached I've hovered over the 'edit' link alongside the node 'Head of Development' which shows node/5 in the bottom left.

[image]

The issue I've got is that I want to link back to a page view which doesn't show alongside all the other content. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the View is set up as a page, you are required to define the path under Page Settings:

[image]

So, given this example you would create a link with:

```
<?php print l(t('Link to Monkey!'), 'monkey'); ?>
```

You can find more information on the l() function [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [l](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7) function to build links in Drupal.

```
  <?php print l(t('Back to blog'), 'node/22'); ?>
```

I see Content administration page on you screenshot. If you want to build link to this page you may use next piece of code

```
  <?php print l(t('Content'), 'admin/content'); ?>
```